# how to uninstall nativescript on mac. Installation issue on mac

Tags: macos, npm, nativescript, nativescript-cli

Trying to upgrade the nativeScript on mac, before that uninstall it by "npm uninstall -g nativescript" but not removing properly.

screenshot:

[image]

How to remove the nativescript from my mac. Help me with this.

Comment: Try checking the location of existing NativeScript in your mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use After:
npm cache clean --force